# Matlab assign Value to String

Tags: matlab

I got an array with values which are either 1 or 2 like:

`val = [1,2,2,1,...]`

Now I want to generate a new array in which every value of val is replaced with a String like:

`str = {'accept', 'not accept','not accept', 'accept',...}`

Can someone help me to get it done with Matlab?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a cell like `options = {'accept', 'not accept'}`. One solution can be:

```
str =options(val)
```

So, if `val = [1 2 2 1 ...]` the result would be:

```
str = {'accept', 'not accept','not accept', 'accept',...}
```